# Using python3.6 and BeautifulSoup. I get are the hrefs, but I cannot download them

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to download files from an html source.
e.g.

```
<a class="el" href="classcs1graphics_1_1Circle.html">Circle</a>
<a class="el" href="classcs1graphics_1_1Polygon.html">Polygon</a>
```

I get all the hrefs, but I'm trying to get the actual contents of the href.

Code below gets the above (lots of them) and does it quickly. How can I get the contents of these hrefs?  Thanks in advance.

Ed

```
import urllib.request, urllib.error, urllib.parse
from lxml import html
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#get the data from the URL
udata = requests.get('http://www.cs1graphics.org/doc/1.0/hierarchy.html')

#feed it to BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(udata.text,'html.parser')

#get all the <a table records
number_list_items = soup.find_all('a')

#get the rows in the records
for li_row in number_list_items:
    print(li_row)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to call `requests.get()` in loop to download the content. it use relative URL so you have to define base URL

```
base_url = 'http://www.cs1graphics.org/doc/1.0/'
#get the data from the URL
udata = requests.get(base_url + 'hierarchy.html')

#feed it to BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(udata.text,'html.parser')

#get all the <a table records
number_list_items = soup.find_all('a')

# get the rows in the records
for li_row in number_list_items:
    fileName = li_row['href']
    url = base_url + fileName
    print(url)      
    udata = requests.get(url)
    with open(fileName, 'w') as f:
        f.write(udata.text)
```

Comment: thanks, I'll give it a try. I'm not up to speed yet on plating with html.

Comment: edited the answer, i have typo in loop `requests.get(base_url + 'hierarchy.html')` where it should be  `requests.get(base_url + li_row['href'])`

Comment: I guess I'm a little dense here. I don't understand how to download the files. do I use something like wget here inside the loop?

Comment: just got your edit --- that makes more sense.  Thanks

Comment: you're welcome, if it solved please mark the answer as correct.

Comment: ewwink you got me on the right track!  Once the correct url was built, I was able to download the file manually with wget.  All I have to do now is probably import os and use wget in the loop. get back to you later --- but this was a great help!  Thanks a lot ---- Ed

Comment: Thanks ewwink! Got all the files and the links  in each one work just fine, Other than just perusing the web, is there a good working reference book for using python to navigate & suck up info from the web. I just seems too scattered. I don't want to have to keep asking for help here on the stack.    Thanks again!   ed